# Recorrer una coleccion ul > li con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Con una estructura HTML `ul`>`li` simple :

```
<ul class="contenido">
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
</ul>
```

Con un JS :

```
let li = document.getELementByClassName("contenido");

function getAnimacion(){
   for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
       li[i].style.color = "red";
    });

   }

getAnimacion();
```

**INTENCION**

Cuando te posiciones encima de un ítem ("`li`") este debe cambiar de color a rojo... pero no cambia.

Si lo haces de manera individual fuera del bucle dándole la posición a mano si.

```
li[0].addEventListener("mouseover",function()){
     li[0].style.color = "red";
}
```

Lo he intentado con `querySelector`, con `function async`... y no he logrado nada si alguien puede mostrarme y explicarme como puedo hacerlo y en que fallo lo agradecería.

Comment: Quieres que cambie solo color rojo o cuando se aleje el mouse se vuelva a su color original

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un querySelector sobre la clase `.contenido`, luego obtener todos los `li`s y recorrerlos para agregarles el `eventListener`.

```js
let lis = document.querySelector('.contenido').getElementsByTagName('li');

[].forEach.call(lis, element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
     element.style.color = 'red';
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="contenido">
     <li class="contenido_item">index1</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index2</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos que debes seleccionar son los que tienen como className `contenido_item`.
Además el método a utilizar para seleccionar los elementos está mal escrito, debe ser `getElementsByClassName`.

```js
let li = document.getElementsByClassName("contenido_item");

function getAnimacion(){
   for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
       li[i].style.color = "red";
    });
  }
}

getAnimacion();
```

```html
<ul class="contenido">
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
     <li class="contenido_item">index</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let li = document.getELementByClassName("contenido_item");

li.onmouseover = getAnimacion();

function getAnimacion() {
 li.style.color = "red";
}
```

Asi seria individualmente tomando la clase de cada li.

Comment: Tienes 2 errores en tu codigo. El primero es esta mal escrito `getElementsByClassName`, deberia ser asi. El segundo error es que no funcionaria tu codigo porque el metodo `getElementsByClassName` devuelve una coleccion

Comment: Buenas observaciones @JuanRivera, anexo a lo que ya te mencionan Tomas deberías o bien indicar el índice el elemento deseado o bien iterarlos con un ciclo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente agregando un `id` en el `ul` y quitando las demas clases. Esto porque usando el `id` sera el padre para dar evento a los `li`

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("contenido");

ul.addEventListener("mouseover", function( li) {
  li.target.style.color = "red";
}, false);
```

```html
<ul id="contenido">
     <li>index</li>
     <li>index</li>
     <li>index</li>
</ul>
```